# Easiest way to build [0, 0, ..., 0] (with n zeroes)

Tags: python

How can I build `[0, 0, ..., 0]`, a list with `n` zeroes? I've tried

```
for i in range(0, n):
    a[i] = 0
```

but that throws an error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
[0] * n
```

If you want `n` mutable objects instead of `n` zeros, use a list comprehension, e.g.:

```
[[] for dummy in range(n)]
```

Comment: Note that this is acceptable because numbers are immutable; don't try this with a mutable type.

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness: if `a` had been initialized to `[]`, then your loop would have worked if the body were replaced with `a.append(0)`.  Not the approach I would recommend, though.